# i want to get auto suggest @gmail.com when iam type gmail id

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I have a login form that ask email id and password. In the email id field, I want to implement auto suggestion as `@gmail.com` when I am typing xxx@. Can any one tell how to implement this? I am using the code that is given below

```
$(function () {
  var acList = ['gmail.com',
    'yahoo.com',
    'hotmail.com'
    ];
  var lastDot = -1;
  $("#tags").autocomplete({
    minLength: 0,
    source: function (request, response) {
      if (lastDot>=0) {
        response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
        acList, extractLast(request.term.substring(lastDot+1))));          
      }
    },
    focus: function () {
      return false;
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
      var terms = split(this.value);
      terms.pop();
      terms.push(ui.item.value);
      terms.push("");
      this.value = this.value.substr(0,lastDot+1);
      this.value += terms.join("");
      return false;
    }
  }).on("keypress", function (e) {
    var keys = [];
    keys.unshift(e.which);
    if (String.fromCharCode(keys[0]) == "@") {
      lastDot =  $("#tags").val().length;
    }
  });
  function split(val) {
    return val.split(/,\s*/);
  }
  function extractLast(term) {
    return split(term).pop();
  }
});

<input id="tags" type="input" />
```

Comment: can anyone please tell me how to implement this

Comment: And how did you know that its a gmail id while you are typing the email ?

Comment: please consider xxx@gmail.com is my mail id. and when iam typing xxx@ show suggestions as gmail.com, yahoo.com etc

Comment: Seems like your code is already doing what you ask for... See this [codePen](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MXRBed?editors=1010) - So what is the issue?

Comment: <input id="tags" type="text" autofocus="true" name="uname" required /> this is my imput field and i place script inside head tag

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your head :

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You forgot to load the jQuery library, which is used in your script.

Regards.

Comment: but now also shows the same issue ie not suggesting anything when iam entering my gmail id